# Is it secure to send the authResponse to the server via javascript?

Tags: security, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

I've seen a few questions here on stackoverflow already:

- [How authenticate a facebook user secure via javascript?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14187355/how-authenticate-a-facebook-user-secure-via-javascript)
- [Facebook login plugin with server side access to users data](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12215709/facebook-login-plugin-with-server-side-access-to-users-data)
- [How to securely authorize a user via Facebook's Javascript SDK](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14186146/how-to-securely-authorize-a-user-via-facebooks-javascript-sdk)

Especially the last one seems to be helpful.

So if I call `FB.getLoginStatus()` and this returns me the signed_request and issued_at time I need only to pass those two parameters to the server, parse it and check it by calling the Facebook API on the server side in order to check if the passed parameters are correct?

The application I plan to write won't be able to use cookies for sending those things to the server. Instead I'd need to send it via websockets(secure) to the server. So the transmission is basicly secured through TLS but I don't know if it's enough to just check then the signed_request and the issued_at time.

Comment: The signed_request can only be verified by your app, since verifying it needs your app secret.

Comment: yeah I know that. I do now send the signed_request and expiresIn and verify the signed_request on the server side, as well as check the expiresIn time.